# how to filter view content by field value?

Tags: 7, views

I have one content type (article) and in that I have created field "Article category" which is Term reference.

I have created a view page where I am displaying (content title, Article category and post date) and Filter criteria is (Content: Published (Yes), Content: Type (= Article), Content: Article category (exposed)) and created Exposed form block.screenshot attached.
[image]

when I use exposed filter and check and categories filter is working as expected.

but my client also want to filer data when she click on any field category.

[image]

please assist to solve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to drupalstackexchange, please tell me more about what you want. you mean instead click on checkbox it work with click on category label?

Comment: Hi Zhileva, Page should  filtered by category (either by clicking the sidebar filters or by clicking on a category  field underneath the article title ).